# R changing geom_smooth y axis into percent

Tags: r

```
time = c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
biomarker = c(10,50,20,20,80,40)
       
sdata = data.frame(id,time,biomarker)

ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data = sdata, aes(x=time, y = biomarker), method=loess, color = 'red')
```

How do you change the y axis on the smooth curve to be percentage change instead of absolute changes. For example if the mean baseline value at time 1 is 15 and at time 2 it is 30 the y axis should denote a 100% increase.

[image]

This relates to my marker of interest where the relative change is of interest.

Comment: What "percentage change" are you referring to? What are the numerator and denominator of interests? You don't seem to be plotting changes at all here; you are plotting absolute values. It's not clear how you are trying to interpret this plot.

Comment: Do you want to change your graph labels only, or do you want to compute a new column that is % change in `y1` (based off of the previous value, or something else?), or...

Comment: Hi i have updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the percentage change using `lag` from `dplyr` and plot that like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
sdata = sdata |>
  mutate(change = biomarker - lag(biomarker),
         pct_change = (change/lag(biomarker))*100)
ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data = sdata, aes(x=time, y = pct_change), method=loess, color = 'red') +
  labs(y = 'Percentage change')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>